# Python Script won't run right when double-clicking .py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a semi-noob at Python and programming but my program won't work right when I double click to open the .py file. It will when I run it from command line though and through the IDE (Pycharm). Basically, when double clicking, it will reach the key = input("Enter decode key: ") part and after typing something, it will close. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know my code isn't elegant, it just needs to work. *Python 3.5.2*

If it helps, a sample input would be 23 for the "key" and 142,128,133,123,134,142 for the "encoded". It should output "window" and does successfully in command line and Pycharm.

```
import sys


def main(key, encoded):

    if encoded == 0:               #This should run if program was double-clicked (no arguments)
        encoded = input("Paste encoded JavaScript: ")
        key = input("Enter decode key: ")

    def decode(key, encoded):           #Decode the data
        encoded = encoded.split(',')    #Split each section delimiting by a colon
        decoded = []
        for x in encoded:
            x = int(x) - int(key)       #Subtract the key from the number in each section
            decoded.append(chr(x))      #Change from ASCII decimal code to the ASCII character
        decoded = ''.join(decoded)      #Join back into a string
        print(".")
        print(".")
        print(".")
        print(".")
        print("Encoded data:")
        print(encoded)
        print("Decode key:")
        print(key)
        print("Decoded data:")
        print(decoded)
        return 0

    decode(key, encoded)            #Jump into the decode function
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:          #If length is greater than 1, then there were arguments added upon program execution
            key = sys.argv[1]          #The "key" should be the first argument
            encoded = sys.argv[2]      #The "encoded" data should follow
        else:
            key = 0                    #If length is anything else, then set them to 0 and ask for the data later
            encoded = 0
        main(key, encoded)             #Jump into main function and pass the key and encoded arguments
    finally:
        input("Press Enter to exit")
```

Comment: You could put at the very end: ``input("Press Enter to exit")``

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the title. Originally, I thought it just wasn't pausing at the end. But then I realized it wasn't even making it through the program. It should already pause after printing out the info (where I have the y = input)

Comment: I can't quite tell what's going on. I think there were some formatting errors in your pasted code.

Comment: I've cleaned up the code a little. Basically, if there's an encoded portion of JavaScript for a specific type of redirector that's being used. You paste in the encoded section, say 142,128,133,123,134,142,69,139,134,135,69,131,134,122,120,139,128,134,133,69,127,137,124,125,84 and it separates each section (delimited by a colon) and subtracts the inputted key. Then it joins it back into a string and outputs that. which in the above example would be 'window.top.location.href='

Comment: print your `encoded` after the split. I got some ascii characters in the string I copied supplied by you. Worked fine if I typed it out.

Answer (score 0):

easily put an input('') at the end of your code so the script sticks in there

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping your program with exception handling.

Here is a snippet of what the last section of your code would look like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        # ...
    finally:
        input("Press the enter to exit")
```

By doing this, regardless of whether your program completes successfully or fails, you will get a prompt asking you to press enter. This will give you a chance to read what is one the screen before closing the window.

Just putting an `input("")` at the end of your program will *not* work in the case of program failure, which you indicate may be happening here.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code with that and comments explaining everything. The program pauses (the finally portion) directly after you input the decode key. Why is it not jumping into the decode function?

Comment: The question just got a +1 for formatting - I wish everyone on this site took the care that you have. Could you please try adding `print sys.argv` just before the try statement? It might shed some light.

Comment: So, I tried that and all I got was the path for the file. Which should happen. But, I have an unrelated update. So, I was at work (where this will be used) and had to convert some things down since we are using Python 2.7 there. Once I did this, everything worked just fine. The only things I changed were the print to where there's no parentheses and the input to raw_input. I even did this here at home while still using Python 3.5 and it works as well. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just solved my problem. For some reason, it is stuck on using Python 2.7 on my computer when you double-click a .py even though my path is set to Python 3.5 and I  right click to open with 3.5 and it just opens in 2.7...So, that just opens up a new issue.